# Need help with iFrames

Tags: html

I have an iframe like this :

```
<iframe width="985px" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" height="2100px" src="http://www.myblog.com/search?q=<?php echo $plus ?>searhed"></iframe>
```

Now in the iframe i want to add a button ( or something like that,can be an image),that will navigate to the previous page which the person was browsing.

Its like i want to add "Back" and "Forward" functions in any browser to my iframe.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at javascript function [history.back()](http://de.selfhtml.org/javascript/objekte/history.htm#back)

Comment: But that takes my current page back but not my frame.

Comment: you can also call that on your frame by using something like `parent.frames[0].history.back();` or `nameofmyiframe.history.back();`

Comment: I can't understand can you give me an example or a link for this as well ?